# QWC2 does not display map on host machine

Tags: qgis-server, qwc2

I am using qwc-demo that is running on the virtual machine. It displays the map as required. I use Apache webserver for the machine.

When I try to view it from the host machine, I am able to see the qwc interface, but the map is not displayed.

The only relatable browser console warning is "Loading failed for the  with source “http://192.168.1.95/prod/api_examples.js”." but it is also observed on virtual machine.

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks and other statements of appreciation within your posts.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:
In my case the problem was due to the fact that the server did not have sufficient rights to access the map file. Rising the privileges should help